# XSLT producing a document with multiple default namespaces

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, .net-4.8

I am trying to produce an XML document in the following form:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root xmlns="http://a.example.com">
  <Header xmlns="http://b.example.com">
    <Fr>
      <OrgId>
        <Id>hello</Id>
      </OrgId>
    </Fr>
    <To>
      <OrgId>
        <Id>goodbye</Id>
      </OrgId>
    </To>
  </Header>
  <Body xmlns="http://c.example.com">
    <Trades>
      <Volume>2</Volume>
      <Price>3</Price>
    </Trades>
  </Body>
</Root>
```

I have the following XSLT:
Note this is XSLT 1.0 because I'm using .Net (.Net Framework)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <Root xmlns="http://a.example.com">
      <Header xmlns="http://b.example.com">
        <Fr>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="/Trades">
            <xsl:with-param name="Id">hello</xsl:with-param>
          </xsl:apply-templates>
        </Fr>
        <To>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="/Trades">
            <xsl:with-param name="Id">goodbye</xsl:with-param>
          </xsl:apply-templates>
        </To>
      </Header>
      <Body xmlns="http://c.example.com">
        <Trades>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="/Trades/Trade" />
        </Trades>
      </Body>
    </Root>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/Trades">
    <xsl:param name="Id" />
    <OrgId>
      <Id>
        <xsl:value-of select="$Id"/>
      </Id>
    </OrgId>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Trade">
    <xsl:param name="Id" />
    <Volume>
      <xsl:value-of select="volume"/>
    </Volume>
    <Price>
      <xsl:value-of select="price"/>
    </Price>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But this produces the following XML that does not validate against the 3rd party XSD

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root xmlns="http://a.example.com">
  <Header xmlns="http://b.example.com">
    <Fr>
      <OrgId xmlns="">
        <Id>hello</Id>
      </OrgId>
    </Fr>
    <To>
      <OrgId xmlns="">
        <Id>goodbye</Id>
      </OrgId>
    </To>
  </Header>
  <Body xmlns="http://c.example.com">
    <Trades>
      <Volume xmlns="">2</Volume>
      <Price xmlns="">3</Price>
    </Trades>
  </Body>
</Root>
```

The problem is the **xmlns=""**.

**Why is the default namespace being explicitly reset?**

The solution I've come up with which does validate against the XSD is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <Root xmlns="http://a.example.com">
      <Header xmlns="http://b.example.com">
        <Fr>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="/Trades">
            <xsl:with-param name="Id">hellox</xsl:with-param>
            <xsl:with-param name="namespace">http://b.example.com</xsl:with-param>
          </xsl:apply-templates>
        </Fr>
        <To>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="/Trades">
            <xsl:with-param name="Id">goodbye</xsl:with-param>
            <xsl:with-param name="namespace">http://b.example.com</xsl:with-param>
          </xsl:apply-templates>
        </To>
      </Header>
      <Body xmlns="http://c.example.com">
        <Trades>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="/Trades/Trade">
            <xsl:with-param name="namespace">http://c.example.com</xsl:with-param>
          </xsl:apply-templates>
        </Trades>
      </Body>
    </Root>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/Trades">
    <xsl:param name="Id" />
    <xsl:param name="namespace" />
    <xsl:element name="b:OrgId" namespace="{$namespace}">
      <xsl:element name="b:Id" namespace="{$namespace}">
        <xsl:value-of select="$Id"/>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Trade">
    <xsl:param name="Id" />
    <xsl:param name="namespace" />
    <xsl:element name="c:Volume" namespace="{$namespace}">
      <xsl:value-of select="volume"/>
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:element name="c:Price" namespace="{$namespace}">
      <xsl:value-of select="price"/>
      </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This produces an XML document of this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root xmlns="http://a.example.com">
  <Header xmlns="http://b.example.com">
    <Fr>
      <b:OrgId xmlns:b="http://b.example.com">
        <b:Id>hellox</b:Id>
      </b:OrgId>
    </Fr>
    <To>
      <b:OrgId xmlns:b="http://b.example.com">
        <b:Id>goodbye</b:Id>
      </b:OrgId>
    </To>
  </Header>
  <Body xmlns="http://c.example.com">
    <Trades>
      <c:Volume xmlns:c="http://c.example.com">2</c:Volume>
      <c:Price xmlns:c="http://c.example.com">3</c:Price>
    </Trades>
  </Body>
</Root>
```

This is acceptable as it validates against the XSD, but it feels unnecessarily complicated having to pass the namespace to the template and all the child elements in the templates need to have prefixed namespaces.

**EDIT**
Forgot to add the input XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Trades>
  <Trade>
    <id>
      a
    </id>
    <volume>2</volume>
    <price>3</price>
  </Trade>
</Trades>
```

Comment: *"Why is the default namespace being explicitly reset."* It is not "reset". It simply doesn't exist. No default namespace is declared anywhere on the ancestor axis of `OrgID` and its descendants..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the point you are having problems with is that a [literal result element](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#literal-result-element) inherits the namespaces from its ancestors **in the stylesheet tree**.

If you want to have separate templates to deal with different branches of the input tree, you will have to re-declare the default namespace in each template. (Technically you could declare one of them as the "main" default namespace at the top level of the stylesheet, and then skip one of the declarations at the template level. But that would just add more confusion, IMHO).

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <Root xmlns="http://a.example.com">
        <Header xmlns="http://b.example.com">
            <Fr>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="/Trades">
                    <xsl:with-param name="Id">hello</xsl:with-param>
                </xsl:apply-templates>
            </Fr>
            <To>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="/Trades">
                    <xsl:with-param name="Id">goodbye</xsl:with-param>
                </xsl:apply-templates>
            </To>
        </Header>
        <Body xmlns="http://c.example.com">
            <Trades>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="/Trades/Trade" />
            </Trades>
        </Body>
    </Root>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/Trades" xmlns="http://b.example.com">
    <xsl:param name="Id" />
    <OrgId >
        <Id>
            <xsl:value-of select="$Id"/>
        </Id>
    </OrgId>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Trade" xmlns="http://c.example.com">
    <xsl:param name="Id" />
    <Volume >
        <xsl:value-of select="volume"/>
    </Volume>
    <Price>
        <xsl:value-of select="price"/>
    </Price>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You could probably simplify this by using `xsl:for-each` instead of passing the process to another template.

Comment: Thanks for the response @michael.hor257k

I'm going to do a quick edit of my question because there is a 3rd default namespace.

Comment: Does it make any difference? You should see how it works from the current example.

Comment: Making http://b.example.com as the root default namespace impacts the 3rd default namespace http://c.example.com. See my edits for an explanation

Comment: I have edited my answer. In the future, please do not make such major changes to your question after it has been answered.

Comment: Cheers for that. I couldn't make the leap between putting a default namespace at the stylesheet level and putting them at the template level. Thanks again